# Django Get absolute url for static files

Tags: python, django

In Django, when I use:

```
{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{% static "img/myimage.jpg" %}
```

It produces: 'http://myurl.com//static/img/myimage.jpg'. This produces an error.

How can I remove the double slashes?

The STATIC URL is:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

But I don't think removing the first '/' would be a good idea.

Comment: Can't you simply drop `{% static "img/myimage.jpg" %}` ? Do you really need `{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}` there ?

Comment: I need access to the full path.

Comment: I use `request.build_absolute_uri().rstrip('/')` and passing it as context variable to my template

Answer (score 26):

The `request` object is available within your templates and you can easily access attributes such as `request.scheme` or `request.META.HTTP_HOST` to construct your base URL that you can prepend ahead of your static URL to get the full URL.

Final example would look something like this:

```
<img src="{{request.scheme}}://{{request.META.HTTP_HOST}}{% static 'img/myimage.jpg' %}">
```

Answer (score 20):

The `build_absolute_uri` method builds an absolute uri for the current page. That means that if you're on e.g. 'http://myurl.com/login/', the resulted full url would be 'http://myurl.com/login//static/img/myimage.jpg'.

Instead, use `request.get_host()` (optionally together with `request.scheme` for the url scheme), or preferably, use the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#how-django-uses-the-sites-framework) to set a template variable to the current site domain. The `get_host()` method has [some issues](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host) regarding proxies.

The `get_host()` method will return the current domain without a path appended.

Comment: can you provide full example ?

Comment: Here is an example with `scheme`and `get_host`. `<meta property="og:image" content="{% block og_image %}{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% static 'vitrine/images/logo-open-graph.png' %}{% endblock %}" />` Couldn't make it work with `build_absolute_uri` due to the `//`

Answer (score 7):

I just made a quick template tag for doing this. Create files `/myapp/templatetags/__init__.py` and `/myapp/templatetags/my_tag_library.py`, if you don't have them already, and add the following to `my_tag_library.py`:

```
from django import template
from django.templatetags import static

register = template.Library()

class FullStaticNode(static.StaticNode):
    def url(self, context):
        request = context['request']
        return request.build_absolute_uri(super().url(context))


@register.tag('fullstatic')
def do_static(parser, token):
    return FullStaticNode.handle_token(parser, token)
```

Then in your templates, just `{% load my_tag_library %}` and use e.g. `{% fullstatic my_image.jpg %}`.

In response to earlier comments wondering why someone would need to do this, my particular use case was that I wanted to put a link to a static file inside of an [open graph protocol](http://ogp.me) meta tag, and those links need to be absolute. In development the static files get served locally, but in production they get served remotely, so I couldn't just prepend the host to get the full url.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: For anyone using Python 2.7, I had to write the super portion as `super(FullStaticNode, self).url(context)`

Answer (score 2):

Use this for apps:

```
{{ request.build_absolute_uri|slice:":-1" }}{% static "img/myimage.jpg" %}
```

Use this generally:

```
{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}{% static "img/myimage.jpg" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this worth an update (Django 2+)?

This helped me specifically because I was trying to put a query in the link, i.e. the myimage.jpg was actually pulling from the DB. I needed a way to put it in the src, which was to replace 'myimage.jpg' with {{ img_link_field_in_model }}.

```
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/myimage.jpg">
```

will produce:

```
<img src="/static/img/myimage.jpg">
```

The example of the query is:

```
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/{{img_link_from_model}}">
```

Answer (score -4):

Not entirely sure what you're asking, but since the {% static .. %} is only adding /static/ to the front of your path you specify, you could just do that yourself:

```
{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}static/img/myimage.jpg
```

Not very modular, but then again most times you don't need direct access to the full url since it will just append it onto whatever url you're at if you use it as a src for some html object.

Comment: He wants to know how to remove the second slash, presumably without bypassing the static framework.

Answer (score -6):

`build_absolute_uri` takes the location as an argument which handles the double slash problem. 
Unfortunately you cannot pass arguments via the django template language.

You will need to build a custom template tag or filter which accepts an argument to the `build_absolute_uri` function.

One of the many reasons I prefer Jinja as I can just do this:

```
{{ request.build_absolute_uri(static('img/foo.png')) }}
```

Comment: this is false. you sure can pass arguments with the Django template language, e.g. `{% url 'some-url-name' arg1=v1 arg2=v2 %}` [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)