# How to get absolute URL with domain and protocol in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to add in a template the URL of a static file including the protocol and domain. For relative URLs, I do:

```
{% static "/path/to/image.jpg" %}
```

Here, I would like to get rendered, one of these

```
http://example.com/path/to/image.jpg
http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg
https://example.com/path/to/image.jpg
https://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg
```

depending on how the client is accessing the site.

I have read [Django Get absolute url for static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746238/django-get-absolute-url-for-static-files), but the answers provided there do not address the protocol (e.g. `http`) part of the URL. Solutions that involve `request.build_absolute_uri` do include the protocol, but the function returns the URL of the current page, not of the root of the website, so it is hard to construct a URL from that part and a path to a static file.

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? A root relative URL (what you get by default) will automatically make the browser use the current scheme/domain.

Comment: @solarissmoke schema.org structured data requires some itemprops to be an absolute URL.

Comment: If you're only missing the protocol, you can get that from the request: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L197. It seems there's no built-in way to do this, but it seems easy enough to put together.

Comment: @Tony I updated my answer in the duplicate, since the difference is quite trivial: just add `request.scheme`.