# Django renders the HTML file without including static files(CSS styles, images)

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, email, render

There I have tried to render the HTML file

```
    html_message = get_template('mail.html').render(context=data)
    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        "Subject",
        html_message,
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        ['example@gmail.com', ],
    )
    email.attach_alternative(html_message, 'text/html')
    email.send(fail_silently=False)
```

The HTML file

```
    {% load static %}
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Title</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'mail.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
      <header>
        <div>
          <img class="logo" src="{% static 'logo.svg' %}" alt="">
        </div>
      </header>
    </body>
```

As the Result HTML file was rendered without static files.
**When I'm rendering the HTML like a view, everything works great**

Comment: Which django version you are using?

Comment: Django 4.0, Python 3.8

Comment: Can you show your project's static folder structure?

Comment: \project ~
    \static ~
        logo.svg
        mail.css

Comment: When I'm rendering the HTML like a view, everything works great

Comment: Django works on `MVT` architecture, so making view is necessary and a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the generated part using `static` uses relative urls for static assets (such as `/static/logo.svg`). I think that's the expected behaviour, and since the URL is not absolute (the hostname part is missing), there is no way an email client will be able to get it correctly.

That also explains why it works on the online version.

You might find a good lead here: [Django Get absolute url for static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746238/django-get-absolute-url-for-static-files)

Edit: more precisely, the `static` tag generates the asset path using the  `STATIC_URL` setting, which people tend to default to `static/`. One way to solve your issue would be then to set an absolute base url here instead (ie. `https://your-hostname.com/static/`)